# WXPython GUI to a Website

Tags: wxpython

I have a tool I use at work consistently that I coded in python and i'd like to be able to share it but don't want to give out access to my box.  Is wxpython capable of generating a website that can take in data so I can run it that way without them logging in?

Answer (score 2):

wxPython is based on wxWidgets which uses GTK+ on some platforms. GTK+ has [Broadway backend](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-broadway.html) which produces HTML5 web page which is available through a web browser. So, you can create a web application using GTK+.

You can see the result for pure GTK+ application in this blog post: http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2011/03/15/gtk-html-backend-update/.

Currently, it works also for wxWidgets (using wxGTK) but it does not work for wxPython yet, see related ticket: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14469.

Note that currently, you need to compile manually GTK+ with Broadway and compile also wxWidgets for this GTK+. wxPython needs some patch, so currently the compilation fails.

Comment: Update: Ticket 14469 is closed. Incomplete patch in http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15291. It seems that the general focus is on general GTK+ 3 support and Phoenix.

Answer (score 1):

wxPython is for creating desktop applications, not web apps. However, you might want to take a look at this interesting video: http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/dabo-rich-client-web-applications-in-100-python-1957207

It's about using Dabo, a wrapper around wxPython, in such a way as to create BOTH a desktop app and a web app of sorts. There was another video from PyCon 2009 that had a similar idea, called BILS - http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/the-browser-interface-local-server-bils-application-1957143

Otherwise, I would recommend looking at using a Python web framework like Django or Flask.